# Python epoch - datetime conversion bug?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, pytz

So I have the following code:

```
import pytz
from datetime import datetime


tz = pytz.timezone('Asia/Singapore')

original_time = tz.localize(datetime.now())
original_epoch = original_time.timestamp()
converted_dt = tz.localize(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(original_epoch))
converted_epoch = converted_dt.timestamp()

print('{}\t\t{}'.format(original_time, original_epoch))
print('{}\t\t{}'.format(converted_dt, converted_epoch))
```

And it spits out

```
# Original Time                         Original Epoch
2018-07-16 02:17:41.583510+08:00        1531678661.58351
2018-07-15 18:17:41.583510+08:00        1531649861.58351
# Converted Time                        Converted Epoch
```

Is this a Python bug or am I simply missing something? And either way, how can I convert datetime to epoch and back with confidence that I am getting back the right time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tz.localize()` does not perform any timezone adjustments to the given `datetime`; it just sets its `tzinfo` to the given timezone.  For the timestamps you're using, this means that `tz.localtime()` performs the following:

```
 datetime.now()                           ->  tz.localize(datetime.now())
 2018-07-16 02:17:41.583510                   2018-07-16 02:17:41.583510+08:00

 datetime.utcfromtimestamp(original_epoch) -> tz.localize(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(original_epoch))
 2018-07-15 18:17:41.583510                -> 2018-07-15 18:17:41.583510+08:00
```

Note that the times don't change; only the timezone offset does.  Because the inputs to `tz.localize()` are two different naïve times, you get two different aware times out.

The correct way to construct a `datetime` from a UNIX timestamp and a timezone is to use [`datetime.fromtimestamp()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp) with two arguments:

```
>>> print(datetime.fromtimestamp(1531678661.58351, pytz.timezone('Asia/Singapore')))
2018-07-16 02:17:41.583510+08:00
```

Comment: Thanks Jwodder! Been stumped all night trying to figure it out.